# Why are top-level methods defined in config.ru not accessible to Sinatra::Application?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

If I have a config.ru file like this:

```
def my_method
  1+2
end

require 'my_sinatra_app'

run Sinatra::Application
```

Calling my_method from within my_sinatra_app.rb returns "**undefined method `my_method' for main:Object**".

As a top-level method it should be accessible from everywhere; why is my_method not accessible from within my_sinatra_app.rb?

Comment: where do you use `my_method` in your app?

Comment: at the top-levels of both config.ru and my_sinatra_app.rb (for example within configure ... do blocks)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`config.ru` is `instance_eval`ed in a `Rack::Builder`, so the methods you define there are not in the Top level scope. If you want to have them as top level methods, you could try putting them in another file and `require`ing them from `config.ru`.

ex **config.ru**

```
p self # => #<Rack::Builder:0x1234123412 @ins=[]>

run lambda {|e|[200,{},[""]]}
```

Comment: Thanks. That explains the behavior that was confusing me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could define it as a module:

```
module MyMethodsModule

  def self.my_method
    #Method body
  end

end
```

And then call its methods:

```
::MyMethodsModule.my_method
```

Comment: That doesn't directly answer my question, but I tried it (for science!) and it doesn't work.

Comment: Very strange. In Ruby 1.9.3 and Sinatra (pre) it gladly works. I will check again.